# Cannot Get Array Version of Heap Sort to Work-- Missing Something

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, heapsort

I'm trying to write a version of heap sort which sorts an array. Essentially the idea is that we know where the root is and where the last element is, and where the parents and children of each element is. The idea is to compare each element with its children, starting at the first non-leaf element, and then swapping if its smallest child is less than that element.

The code runs fine but it doesn't seem to be sorting the array of objects, in this case random Integer objects. It is altering the array but it is not properly sorted.

Hopefully someone can see what I'm missing. Here is my code:

```
public HeapSort{

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T[] HeapSort (T[] sortArr)
    {
        /*
         * Throw exception if array is empty.
         */
        if (sortArr[0] == null)
        {
            throw new EmptyCollectionException("Array");
        }

        /*
         * If array only contains one element.
         */
        if (sortArr.length == 1)
        {
            return sortArr;
        }

        /*
         * Otherwise sorting begins at first non-leaf element near end of array.
         */

        /*
         * First possible child
         */

        int current = (sortArr.length-2)/2;
        int leastChild = 2* current +1;

         if (sortArr[leastChild] != null && sortArr[leastChild].compareTo(sortArr[current]) < 0)
            {
                T temp = sortArr[current];
                sortArr[current] = sortArr[leastChild];
                sortArr[leastChild] = temp;

            }
         current--;

        /*
         * Continue until root is reached.
         */
        while (current >= 0)
        {
            int leftChild = 2 * current + 1;
            int rightChild = 2 * (current + 1);
            leastChild = 0;

            if (sortArr[rightChild] == null)    //If only left child.
                leastChild = leftChild;

            /*
             * If left child is less than right child.
             */
            else if (sortArr[leftChild].compareTo(sortArr[rightChild]) < 0)
                leastChild = leftChild;

             /*
              * In all other cases (no left child, or right child is the smallest)
              */
            else
                leastChild = rightChild;

            /*
             * Swap current elem with its least child, if necessary.
             */

            if (sortArr[leastChild].compareTo(sortArr[current]) < 0)
            {
                T temp = sortArr[current];
                sortArr[current] = sortArr[leastChild];
                sortArr[leastChild] = temp;

            }
            current--; 
        }
        return sortArr;         
    }
}
```

Comment: You should step through your code using a debugger and you will exactly see where you are going wrong.

Comment: I have though. There are no errors or anything else being shown.

Comment: While stepping through the code, you should watch your variables and how its value change. At the point that you see unexpected values, thats where you can find the issue. You will have to make that effort.